# Java FX background threads make GUI freeze

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx

I am trying to understand why my Java FX app is freezing when running costly operations in background threads. This is my class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TestApp extends Application {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    primaryStage.setTitle("Test Threads");
    // create grid for the form
    GridPane grid = new GridPane();
    grid.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_CENTER);
    grid.setHgap(10);
    grid.setVgap(10);
    grid.setPadding(new Insets(25, 25, 25, 25));

    TextField tf = new TextField();
    grid.add(tf, 0, 0);

    Button runButton = new Button("Run");
    grid.add(runButton, 0, 1);
    runButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread() + ": starting threads");
            for (int i=0;i<5;i++){
            Task<Integer> task = new Task<Integer>() {

                @Override
                public Integer call() {
                    Random rand = new Random();
                    List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();

                    for (int i=0; i<20000000; i++){
                        numbers.add(rand.nextInt());
                    }
                    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread() + ": generated");

                    return numbers.size();
                }
            };
            new Thread(task).start();
            }
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread() + ": started all threads.");
        }
    });

    StackPane root = new StackPane();
    root.getChildren().add(grid);
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 500, 420));
    primaryStage.show();
}

}
```

Five background threads are created and started when button "Run" is pressed. All the threads run and generate lists with 20000000 integers each. Even though these operations run on other threads, the GUI freezes and I am unable to find the problem.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You appear to be tying up cpu cycles with that tight loop. What if you throw a short `Thread.sleep(1)` inside the loop?

Comment: how many CPU do your have?

Comment: what is the result of `Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()` ?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels It will take too much time to wait 1 millisecond for every number I generate. But I just added a sleep for every 1000 numbers generated and it is better than before, although still freezing regularly

Comment: Yes it will take longer, but it will free the CPU which you're mercilessly throttling here.

Comment: @NicolasFilotto 8 is the number of cores (quad core hyperthreaded)

Comment: Thanks for your replies, I will think about the option of sleeping every now and then on those threads

Comment: check also how your heap usage evolves and the GC activity using the jconsole or jvisualvm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is very simple to explain. The CPU is working really hard.

Lets assume you have 4 cores and 6 Threads (UIThread + 5 compute threads). The 6 Threads have to share those 4 cores. So even the UIThread needs to wait for the scheduler to give him some CPU time and that can take a random amount of time. So your UI may freeze for random time lengths or until 3 compute threads finished.

Comment: In my real case (not in the example I provided initially), I have a quad core hyperthreaded and 2 threads that run in background generating random numbers. Maybe the GUI thread and one of the generating threads are using the same physical CPU

Comment: @LucianIordache: your program will generate several threads, even without the threads that you specifically create. Bottom line is (again) you're throttling the CPU and have to take some measures to prevent this.